# Running the python script creates lots of python.exe process and finally crashes the OS

Tags: python, windows, process, crash

I run the following script (which is an example from the PyGMO website):
link : http://pagmo.sourceforge.net/pygmo/tutorials/adding_a_new_optimization_problem.html

```
---------------------------- CODE -------------------------------
from PyGMO.problem import base
import PyGMO as pgg
class my_problem(base):
    def init(self, dim = 10):
        super(my_problem,self).init(dim)
        self.set_bounds(-5.12,5.12)
        self.dim = dim
    def _objfun_impl(self,x):
        f = 0;
        for i in range(self.dim):
            f = f + (x[i])*(x[i])
        return (f,)
    def human_readable_extra(self):
        return "\n\t Problem dimension: " + str(self.__dim)


prob = my_problem(dim=10)
algo = pgg.algorithm.bee_colony(gen=5)
isl = pgg.island(algo,prob,20)
isl.evolve(1); isl.join()
print isl.population.champion.f
---------------------------- CODE -------------------------------
```

After executing, it starts the optimization without any error or warning. Then if you check the task manager there are a huge number of **python.exe** processes and the number is increasing more and more. And it finally crashes the windows. The same code has the same problem using PyCharm.

I am using:
Spyder 2.2.5 / Pycharm 2.6.3 - win32
Python 2.7.3
Windows 7 - 64bits
the last version of PyGMO

the same problem with the code in the [stochastic optimization problem tutorial](http://pagmo.sourceforge.net/pygmo/tutorials/adding_a_new_stochastic_optimization_problem.html).

Running the code in IDEL, it works well!!

Has anybody experienced the same problem? I reported the bug in the PyGMO website but there is no answer yet.
Any suggestion to find a solution?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: looking for similar cases and probable solutions @Robᵩ.